# Making a bootable pendrive for custom kernel

Tags: kernel, boot, usb-drive, boot-loader, bootable

I read the tutorials to make a mimalistic custom kernel from [here](http://www.jamesmolloy.co.uk/tutorial_html/1.-Environment%20setup.html) and am able to boot it up as explained in the tutorial over a virtual machine using GRUB as the boot loader.

I think it would be more fun if I could do the same over bare hardware using a bootable pendrive. That is use GRUB, pendrive and my Kernel executable to form a bootable pendrive and then boot into the kernel from this pendrive.

**Q1.** I thought of using the normal procedure of how I make a bootable linux pendrive, but my kernel isn't really an iso image, its an elf format executable. Will the normal method work if I somehow convert my executable to iso format ?

**Q2.** Any other ideas / link to some resource how I should proceed ?

**P.S. :** Its NOT Linux kernel per-se, Its absolutely minimal kernel, no file system nothing. Just boots up, prints something on console and can handle keyboard events, thats it.

Answer (score 1):

From a bootup perspective, the kernel file itself is just a configuration option fed to grub.  As long as grub can find the kernel, you should be good to go.

You will however need something to use as a rootfs, so a partition or dd image on your usb key would make sense, and then store your kernel file in there.  Likely you can even get away with putting it right in /boot with all your grub stuff. 
So at minimum you'll need the mbr set up on the usb key to boot, and a filesystem containing your grub configuration... (I was googling around, and see examples of both fat and ext being used for /boot- I know most usb boot key tools use fat for the base, so I would recommend that- but ext should work also I would think.) 
There is some info [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/boot-usb-files.html) with an example for ubuntu.  I think in your position I would create a bootable USB with on of these tools, and then modify it for my needs- that way I get the grub installation, and mbr stuff taken care of for me.

At the end of the day, I think it's a question of how to get grub up and running on the usb key, after that it's just grub config which [this](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/grub.html) link has helped me out in the past.

Answer (score 0):

[Read](http://live.debian.net/) about Debian's live-build system.

There is option `--linux-package` which should point on the linux-kernel.deb, you may specify your own kernel, just pack it into Debian format.